# XML-парсер

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser, парсер, io

[image: img]

Я решил опрбовать новый (для себя) вид сохранения данных в виде XML-документа/
В данном коде меня смущает его уродство. Мне кажется, или в самом деле этот код не оптимален и можно придумать что-нибудь гораздо эффективнее и красивее? Желательно так же учитывать масштабирование (добавления подкаталогов в узлы "Languages", дочерние узлы `languages` и т.д.).

Будьте добры указать на ошибки,
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Картинка то отсутствует на сервере.

Comment: Все, готово, исправил

Comment: Оформляйте код в виде текста. Изображения требуют больше трафика и не всегда удобны в просмотре, особенно на мобильных устройствах.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте [десериализацию XML](https://www.google.ru/?q=.net%20deserialize%20xml).

А вообще для локализации приложения (по-моему) стоит использовать [стандартные средства .Net](https://www.google.ru/?q=.net%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: локализация была взята как пример

Comment: Ну, тогда десериализация - это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: А не могли бы вы дополнить, кроме десериализации, как можно добавлять элементы в определенные узлы? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: при сериализации новые поля класса атоматом добавят нужные узлы в XML

Comment: Также, можно указать в классе имя узла самостоятельно:

VB:

    <XmlElementAttribute(ElementName:="NodeName")> _
    Property NodeProperty As PropertyType

C#: 

    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "NodeName")]
    public PropertyType NodeProperty { get; set; }